# Draw alternate rectangles in boxplots with facets (R, ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, rectangles

I am using the following code.

```
 mtcars2 <- mtcars
 library(ggplot2)
 mtcars2$carb <- as.factor(mtcars2$carb)
 mtcars2$am <- as.factor(mtcars2$am)
 sort_table <- data.frame("carb" = c(1,2,3,4,6,8), 
     "class" = c("class A", "class B", "class A", "class C", "class B", "class A"))
 odd_numbers <- seq(1,6,2)
 mtcars2 <- merge(mtcars2, sort_table, by = "carb")
 ggplot(mtcars2) + 
     geom_rect(data = mtcars2[odd_numbers, ], xmin = odd_numbers - 0.5, xmax = odd_numbers + 
     0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.5) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

This nicely produces this boxplot with alternating shading.
[image]

Now, I would like to add facets for each class, so I use the following code.

```
 ggplot(mtcars2) + 
     geom_rect(data = mtcars2[odd_numbers, ], xmin = odd_numbers - 0.5, xmax = odd_numbers + 
     0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.5) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
     facet_grid(cols = vars(class), scales = "free_x", switch = "x", space = "free") + 
     theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"), strip.background = element_rect(
         color="black", size=0.5, linetype="solid"))
```

This produces the following boxplot.
[image]

Unfortunately, the shading is now only applied to the first facet. How can I apply continuous shading throughout the plot, so to each facet, so that there is another rectangle behind `carb = 6`? Thank you.

Comment: See the output of `mtcars[odd_numbers, ]` it only has `class A`!

Comment: @M-M - Yes, you are right. Do you have a suggestion on how to change the code to correct that, please? Thank you.

Comment: @ Sylvia Well that's not the code, that's your data which does not have anything for other facets, hence you don't see any other `geom_rect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things will show up the appropriate facet, based on the facet variable that is present in the data.frame you are giving. Give a proper data.frame, with proper mapping, e.g.:

```
df_tile <- data.frame(carb = c(1, 8, 6), class = c('class A', 'class A', 'class B'))

ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_tile(aes(x = factor(carb), y = 1, height = Inf, width = 1), data = df_tile, alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    facet_grid(cols = vars(class), scales = "free_x", space = "free") + 
    theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"), strip.background = element_rect(
        color="black", size=0.5, linetype="solid"))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for `geom_rect` though, does it? (genuinely asking)

Comment: The same principle, using a correct data.frame and mapping, also works for `geom_rect`. However, since you have a discrete x-axis in this example `geom_tile` is much easier to use.

Comment: Well this is what I get for ```geom_rect(data = df_tile, aes(xmin = carb - 0.5, xmax = carb + 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.5)```  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBiyY.png

Comment: @M-M it looks like you still have a numeric variable on the x-axis, whereas this answer converts it to a factor